# Forward declaration not working when using as argument in a member function

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

My forward declaration for `class B;` before class `A` doesn't work in the below  code, even when [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1886701/3835272) mentions that a forward declaration of an incomplete type should work when used in arguments of a function.

It throws an error in `A::func()` saying "undefined type B". What should be the fix for this, and why does my forward declaration not work in this scenario?

Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "in A's default ctor" << endl;
    }

    void func(B b1)
    {
        cout << "in A's func" << endl;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "in B's default ctor" << endl;
    }

    B(const B& b1)
    {
        cout << "in B's copy ctor" << endl;
    }

    B& operator=(const B& b1)
    {
        cout << "in B's copy assignment operator" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    
};    

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.func(b);
}
```

Comment: Separate declaration and definition. Declare the `A::func` function first, then after `B` has be defined, define (implement) `A::func`.

Comment: The problem is that `A::func` needs the full definition of `B` to be able to be implemented. It doesn't need it for just a declaration.

Comment: An incomplete type can only be used as reference or pointed to. You shall not use it for a value parameter.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. C++11 and C++17 are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @273K apologies, will keep in mind for future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++17 Standard (6.2 One-definition rule, p.#5)

> A class type T must be complete if
>
> (5.9) — a function with a return type or argument type of type T **is
> defined** (6.1) or called (8.2.2), or

To avoid the error define the member function  `func` outside the class `A`  after the definition of the class `B`. For example

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    //...
    void func(B b1);
    //...
};

class B
{
    //...
};

void A::func(B b1)
{
    cout << "in A's func" << endl;
}
```

Or without the forward declaration like

```
class A
{
public:
    //...
    void func(class B b1);
    //...
};

class B
{
    //...
};

void A::func(B b1)
{
    cout << "in A's func" << endl;
}
```